# Plotting a parabola: dimension too large message

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}%----- this
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[  scale=.01]
  \draw[domain=-30:30,
     /pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed ] plot (\x,{(\x)^2});
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I used a two year old suggestion of yours to try to plot `y = x^2`  with `domain = -30:30`
as shown above.  But I get the dimension too large message that your response above averted with a different math function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The default unit is 1cm, so you're asking for 900cm = 9m, which is too much for TeX.

Comment: If you use `[y=0.01cm,x=0.2cm]` instead of `[scale=0.01]`, it compiles fine.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

egreg and Jake are right. In this case you don't need `fpu`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[ y=0.01cm,x=0.2cm]
  \draw[domain=-30:30 ] plot (\x,{(\x)^2});
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Explanations :**

With TeX, you can't manipulate dim > 16 384 pt or  5.75m so the code

```
￼\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0)--(600,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

gives **Dimension too large** but TeX can manipulate big integers < 2^31 - 1

An idea is to use the code

```
￼￼￼\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.01 cm]
  \draw (0,0)--(600 cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but you get another **Dimension too large** because 600 cm is a length > 575 cm

Good is the next code

```
￼\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.01 cm]
  \draw (0,0)--(600,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

600 is a number and the length used is 6 cm

Comment: Avoid the `minimal` class for examples.

Comment: @egreg yes I agree with you. I used the code of the question but I forgot to change the class