# Limitations associated with getting length as number

Tags: tikz-pgf, lengths

I am representing actual object dimensions with scaled down graphics which capture the relative proportions of the objects (for instance, imagine a simple set of three or four line segments).  I would like to annotate the length of a nominal segment on the graphic using that segments actual length.  I store the actual lengths using the `\newlength` and `\setlength` commands.  I apply a suitable scaling factor to these segments by operating on the declared actual lengths in order to compute lengths as they should appear in print.  [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15001/getting-length-as-number) link provides several possible solutions, e.g.

```
\newcommand*{\getlength}[2]{%
   % Convert to `cm` and round to two fractional digits:
   \pgfmathsetmacro#1{round(3.51459804*#2)/100.0}%
}
```

When I provide a value of 180 cm

```
\newlength{\lengtha}
\setlength{\lengtha}{180cm}
\getlength{\annotlengtha}{\lengtha}
```

I encounter some restriction, that is, I receive a Dimension too large error message.  Might someone explain the limitations associated with this approach?

Comment: A recent answer with relevant info http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125617/plotting-a-parabola-dimension-too-large-message

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere on this site, [Dividing dimensions to get a count](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85717/dividing-dimensions-to-get-a-count/85724#85724), percusse explained how egreg taught him (and now me) to turn lengths into dimensionless numbers using "count" variable types.  One can assign a length to the count, and it turns it into a large integer (representing the length in TeX internal units).

Then, you can divide two counts to get a dimensionless ratio, for example.  A size of 180cm poses no problem for this technique.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\begin{document}
\newcount\mycounta
\newcount\mycountb
\newlength{\lengtha}
\setlength{\lengtha}{180cm}
\newlength{\lengthb}
\setlength{\lengthb}{30cm}
\mycounta=\lengtha
\mycountb=\lengthb
\the\mycounta~\the\mycountb

\FPdiv\result{\the\mycounta}{\the\mycountb}
\result

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85717/dividing-dimensions-to-get-a-count/85724#85724 ;)

Comment: @percusse Mea culpa. I will revise to give credit.

Comment: Oh no, give the credit to egreg not to the question please :p

Comment: @percusse, the citation train is getting pretty long 8^)

Comment: Indeed, but he explained it to me in chat so I had to use that disclaimer :)